# Rally addnew interrupt creation using beforecreate event

Tags: rally

**The Problem**

I am trying to get around one of the known issues of the rallyaddnew button by setting fields based on different combobox values.  This works fine, but there are some combinations the user can enter than I can only catch after they have elected to create a rollup or feature.

**The Question**

I made a listener for the beforecreate event, and I can tell when I want to prevent the creation of this portfolioitem.  Is there any way to prevent it from being created?

All I am doing right now is:

```
Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'You are creating a feature/rollup with invalid options.  Please delete this record and try again.');
```

But, the record is still created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example where a card is created on a board, and based on the selection in the Iteration box,a story is scheduled accordingly. Except a creation of a new card is interrupted if a certain condition is met. If the condition is met, it returns false:

```
 return false;
```

and new item is not created:

```
_onBeforeCreate: function(addNewComponent, record) {
            var currentDate = new Date();
            console.log(this.iterationCombobox.getValue());
                        var startDate = this.iterationCombobox.getRecord().get("StartDate");
            if (startDate > currentDate){
                  console.log("in the future");
                          return false;
            }
            record.set('Iteration', this.iterationCombobox.getValue());
}
```

Comment: This is a standard pattern in Ext JS and Rally's SDK.  Returning false from an event listener for a 'beforexyz' event will halt the 'xyz' operation.

Comment: I have started to notice that now as I am looking through the SDK - should have caught it the first time!